# Just lunched my first create-app-react npm start and localhost , 127.0.0.1 not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of learning react and node js. I just created a react app then passed npm start on the terminal the localhost:3000 is not responding a says : "This site can’t be reached localhost took too long to respond." I then went to the public folder of the react app and clicked on the index.html to lunch on google chrome, it just gives a blank page. Please help !

Comment: did you run `npm install` first?

Comment: yes I even installed many npm packages

Comment: Do you have another project running on your localhost?

Comment: No, I have never even worked on my localhost

Comment: What commands did you use to `just created a react app`? Did you use npx like the [official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/)? What is the response in the console when you gave the `npm start` command?

Comment: npx create-react-app I was doing the netninja react tutorial on youtube. The  npm start command says : compiled successfully You can now view my-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 0):

1. open **quick heal total security**.
2. click on **Internet & Network**.
3. Turn off **Firewall Protection**.

Again run **npm start**